# Javascript: перемещение по div, как по google maps

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Есть div, который намного больше размера окна. Ищу такую библиотеку или способ, чтобы по этому элементу можно было перемещаться как в гугл картах (драгать и масштабировать скроллом). В этом div есть другие элементы

Comment: Задача понятна, ждите, скоро будет решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас устроит такой вариант?

```js
Element.prototype.makeDraggable=function(){
  var o=this

  var prevx =  document.body.firstElementChild.scrollLeft = document.body.firstElementChild.scrollWidth / 4
  var prevy = document.body.firstElementChild.scrollTop = document.body.firstElementChild.scrollHeight / 4

  o.style.left = o.parentNode.clientWidth / 2 - o.clientWidth / 2
  o.style.top = o.parentNode.clientHeight / 2 - o.clientHeight / 2

  var scale = 1.0

  var prevent = false

  function onwheel(e)
  {
   var el = e.target.closest(".container")
   if(!el) return
   e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);

   e = e || window.event;

   var c = el.firstElementChild

   var d = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta

   if(prevent || d == 0) return

   scale += (d * 0.001) * scale

   if(scale > 3.0) scale = 3.0
   else if(scale < 0.1) scale = 0.1

   o.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ", " + scale + ")"
  }

  if (window.addEventListener) {
    if ('onwheel' in window) {
      window.addEventListener("wheel", onwheel);
    } else if ('onmousewheel' in window) {
      window.addEventListener("mousewheel", onwheel);
    } else {
      window.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onwheel);
    }
  } else {
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onwheel);
  }

  o.onmousedown=function(e){

   prevent = true

   var offsetX=e.pageX-(parseInt(o.style.left) || 0)
   var offsetY=e.pageY-(parseInt(o.style.top) || 0)

   document.onmousemove=function(e) {

    o.style.left=Math.max(Math.min(e.pageX-offsetX,o.parentNode.clientWidth-100),- o.clientHeight * scale + 100) + 'px'
    o.style.top=Math.max(Math.min(e.pageY-offsetY,o.parentNode.clientHeight-100),- o.clientWidth * scale + 100) + 'px'
   }
   document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    prevent = false
    document.onmousemove=o.onmouseup=null
   }
  }
  o.ondragstart = function(){return 0}
 }

var makeDraggable = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0].makeDraggable()
}
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.map * {
 position:absolute;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

.container {
  background: #EEE;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="makeDraggable()">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="map">
   <div style="left:10px;top:70px;background:brown;"></div>
   <div style="left:150px;top:40px;background:blue;"></div>
   <div style="left:20px;top:30px;background:yellow;"></div>
   <div style="left:60px;top:20px;background:white;"></div>
   <div style="left:110px;top:70px;background:white;"></div>
   <div style="left:250px;top:40px;background:green;"></div>
   <div style="left:120px;top:30px;background:gray;"></div>
   <div style="left:160px;top:20px;background:red;"></div>
   <div style="left:10px;top:170px;background:white;"></div>
   <div style="left:150px;top:140px;background:yellow;"></div>
   <div style="left:20px;top:130px;background:white;"></div>
   <div style="left:60px;top:120px;background:green;"></div>
   <div style="left:110px;top:170px;background:red;"></div>
   <div style="left:250px;top:140px;background:white;"></div>
   <div style="left:120px;top:130px;background:magenta;"></div>
   <div style="left:160px;top:120px;background:brown;"></div>
   <div style="left:60px;top:120px;background:green;"></div>
   <div style="left:110px;top:270px;background:red;"></div>
   <div style="left:250px;top:240px;background:white;"></div>
   <div style="left:120px;top:230px;background:magenta;"></div>
   <div style="left:160px;top:220px;background:brown;"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: идеально. Большое спасибо

Comment: можете скопировать это сюда, если хотите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742510/javascript-google-maps-like-experience-in-viewing-div